# WP8.1 Detecting screen capture occurred

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I know how to prevent a user from performing a screen capture on WP8.1 Now I want to allow screen capture and keep track of who does this.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
public async Task StartScreenshotDetection()
{
    try
    {
        var picturesLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        string picsPath = picturesLibrary.Path;

        StorageFolder screenshotsLibrary = await picturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("Screenshots");
        String[] types = { ".png" };
        var options = new Windows.Storage.Search.QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, types);

        if (screenshotsLibrary.AreQueryOptionsSupported(options))
        {
            var query = screenshotsLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);

            query.ContentsChanged += QueryContentsChanged; //subscription

            var throwawayResult = await query.GetFilesAsync(); // needed to get events to fire

            int a = 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        int b = 1;
    }
}

void QueryContentsChanged(Windows.Storage.Search.IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
{
    var a = 1;
    // handle changes
}
```

The issue I'm having is creating a new QueryOptions throws Unimplemented exception. The docs seem to imply WP8.1 is supported.

Is there another way to detect screen capture? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.x has a very basic implementation of the query APIs and doesn't support change notifications. There is no way to know that a capture has occurred. Even if the query API worked, it probably would not be a good solution since there are other reasons why pictures could show up there (eg, synced from OneDrive) that would trigger your event handler.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. How about the same question with Windows 10. Any way to detect screen capture has occurred?

Comment: The Storage API support is better, but not really useful. There is no new API to give you a notification that I'm aware of in 10.